# Why does the sentence uses a question form, but it is put a period in the end?

Tags: questions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> People can watch dancing displays or can take part in different games. **Nowhere, however, **do** they have more fun than in the Mexican town of Puebla**.

Why does the sentence in bold use a question form, but there is a period in the end?

Comment: It just so happens that the cited (rather "literary") usage reverses the normal English *subject + verb* sequence, which *also* happens with actual questions. But the cited example *isn't* a question (not even a "rhetorical" one), so there's no reason to look for a question mark. The reversal here is because of initial "negative polarity" ***nowhere*** and auxiliary ***do***. You'll see the same thing with, for example ***Only rarely** does he leave the house, **Seldom** does he visit*.

Comment: It would be a question like this: "Is there anywhere where they have more fun than in the Mexican town of Puebla?" And the answer would be like in the OP's post: "No, nowhere do they have more fun than in the Mexican town of Puebla."

Comment: Is this a confusion between [SVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object_word_order) and [V2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order), perhaps?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an inversion, but not a question.

In formal English, with a negative adverb like "nowhere" or restrictive like "only" in initial position, the auxiliary verb inverts with the subject:

> I can find my keys nowhere -> Nowhere can I find my keys.

> I will visit you only on Saturday -> Only on Saturday will I visit you.

> I rarely play tennis -> Rarely do I play tennis.

Because the sentence isn't a question, it doesn't end with a question mark.

[More examples](https://test-english.com/explanation/b2/inversion-negative-adverbials/)

Comment: Re: "In formal English, with a negative adverb like 'nowhere' or restrictive like 'only' in initial position, the auxiliary verb inverts with the subject": This wording is misleading, insofar as it suggests that this is specific to formal English. In fact, this inversion is required in colloquial English as well (consider e.g. "never have I ever [...]"; something like \*"never I've ever [...]" would not be grammatical); it's just that these adverbs don't usually take initial position outside of formal English, so it doesn't come up as much.

Comment: I guess it's grammatical, but "I can find my keys nowhere" sounds weird. The idiomatic statement would be "I can't find my keys anywhere".

Answer (score 7):

Nowhere, however, do they have more fun than in the Mexican town of Puebla.
Compare that to:
They don't have more fun anywhere than in the Mexican town of Puebla.

That sentence is not a question. **If you start a sentence like that with the word nowhere, it requires using the auxiliary like that.**

Nowhere do they make better soup than here.
Compare that to:
They don't make better soup anywhere than here.

Nowhere **did** the Vikings **sail** more quickly.
The Vikings **didn't sail anywhere** more quickly.

There are other cases of words that also do this; mostly adverbs of frequency like rarely, seldom, never and frequently. Sometimes the sentence can be more literary but sometimes not.

**Never had she seen** such a mess in an office. It is more written than spoken but can also be spoken.